# JSF 2.0 Encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, jsf-2

What settings and considerations are necessary for making a JSF 2.0 application (on Tomcat 6) use UTF-8 encoding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

listed below are two great articles about this subject.

They were by written by balusC, who preaches here.

[The one about UTF-8 support](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

[The other about jsf2 integration and with eclipse](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html)

Comment: It would be good to have an excerpt from the given links in the answer itself, keeping them as a reference. That way if the links get broken one day, the information will still be available here ;-)