# How to solve encoding problems when using strange characters of titles in JSF and Primefaces

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, character-encoding, primefaces

I am in trouble with encoding values. Well I am developing a web page with spanish content, and it uses tittles like ó,á,è, etc, or characters like ñ. Then when I pressed the button to save the values, I guess the ajax event for a button didn't take the encodig, them I add   `encoding='ISO-8859-1'`, and it worked. But I have an autocomplete for countries in primefaces that also use an ajax event to proccess information, and for this field the encoding doesn't work and before to add `encoding='ISO-8859-1'` it worked. Well when solve one, the other one failed, and vice versa.

Happen that I need the country to consult the states and list them.

Web code:

```
<p:autoComplete id="pais" value="#{personal.pais}"   
                    completeMethod="#{personal.listPaises}" forceSelection="true" required="true" effect="fade" scrollHeight="400" 
                    var="p"  itemLabel="#{p}" itemValue="#{p}" requiredMessage="Es necesario seleccionar país" label="País" validator="#{personal.validatePaises}" >
                     <p:column style="width:80%" >  
                      #{p} 
                      </p:column>
                    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="departamento" />  
                 </p:autoComplete>
```

Java Code:

```
public void setPais(String pais) {
        int codPais = pDao.getPaisCod(pais); 
        departamentosList = pDao.listDepatamentosByPais(codPais);
        this.pais = pais;
    }
```

For example if I choose **España** as Country in jsf form, in the bean is taken as **Espa±a**.

I need unify the encodig.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Thanks @LuiggiMendoza, but it doesn't work. I have tried it and the autocomplete worked, but not when save the form .

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4923607/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Surely ñ is a valid character in Latin-1/ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @AlanKrueger I had a similar problem before using ISO-8859-1 encoding but I don't have the JSF project with the problem/solution atm.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Debes hablar español así que te digo, entiendo tu punto de vista con UTF-8, pero creeme que ya lo he intentado y no funciona para cuando presiono el boton guardar, creo que son 2 eventos ajax diferentes uno para el autocompletar y otro para el evento guardar lo que hay en el formulario, si uso utf-8 funciona uno pero el otro no.

Comment: Hablo español (lengua materna) pero el lenguaje para utilizar en StackOverflow es inglés. Have you checked the links inside the answer in the link posted on my last comment?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. Of course I've checked the links, and I understand it. But I dont´t understand why It is happening in this case.

Comment: Also ensure your editors/IDEs are using the correct encoding. I've run into problems where Eclipse by default got configured with your system default encoding (often Cp1252 in Windows) instead of Latin-1 or UTF-8 or whatever you're intending to use.

Comment: @AlanKrueger Ok, I will check it, but who should to have the encoding is the application server.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use UTF-8, it will support any character and more importantly it is the only encoding that everything has in common. Often something will only work with UTF-8, such as many JSON implementations. And when that isn't the case, JSON cannot support ISO-8859-1 anyways.

For instance, primeface's Ajax uses jQuery.param, which uses `encodeURIComponent`, which uses URL encoding that is [based on UTF-8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.3).

So if you want to unify encoding, UTF-8 is your only option.

Btw, by "use UTF-8", I don't mean just to put UTF-8 in a random place that seems right but actually ensure UTF-8 is the declared and physical encoding everywhere in your project.

Comment: I know that my problem was with ajax request of outocomplete and commandButton. Them I try everything and didn't work. well I solve my proble changing my jsf commandButton to Primefaces commandButton.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my problem was with ajax request of autocomplete and commandButton.Then I tried everything and didn't work. well I solve my problem changing my jsf commandButton to Primefaces commandButton.

Before

`<h:commandButton value="submit" action="Periodico?faces-redirect=true" actionListener="#{personal.insertarUsuario}" />`

After

`<p:commandButton value="submit" action="Periodico?faces-redirect=true" actionListener="#{personal.insertarUsuario}" />`

And so I solve my problem. Thanks a lot for your time and answers