# Client->Server encoding breaks

Tags: jsf-2, entity

I've got problems with encoding in (I think so) Entity. In more details I've got composite component which is responsible for inplace editing - user clicks on text, clicks save and data are saved in database. The problem is that when user enters some non-english chars (diacritic chars?) encoding breaks. For example if user will enter polish char `ą` in Entity I get something like that `ºÄ`. Data are stored in mysql database where encoding is set to UTF-8, page on which data are shown is also encoded in UTF-8. I've checked that problem appears after sending data from client (browser) to server but I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. All I had to do was to add character encoding filter to web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Note that this works only when the webapp is deployed to Tomcat, not other servers. As such, your webapp is **tight coupled** to Tomcat (even more, a specific minimum Tomcat version!) and essentially *unportable* to other server makes or older Tomcat versions. Rather create your own filter (only 1 line of business code required) or use a JSF utility library such as OmniFaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139713/how-to-solve-encoding-problems-when-using-strange-characters-of-titles-in-jsf-an/15144169#15144169